# Books about modern mathematics

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Are there any books that give overviews of active subfields mathematics? I'd like one that introduces a subfield then informally discusses a few theorems and proofs from the subfield.
Ideally, it's aimed at beginning graduate students who want to broaden their horizons.

I know about *Theorems of the 21st Century* by Bogdan Grechuk, but it doesn't go too deep into the math.

Comment: Stillwell "Elements of Mathematics" is pretty good.

Comment: The question asks for opinion based answers. Voted to close.

Comment: @markvs Sorry, but wouldn't all reference requests answers be opinion based?

Comment: "Mathematics and its history" by Stilwell

Comment: @user816709: You can ask, for example, in which paper a certain theorem appeared first. It is not opinion based.  Asking "Are there any books that give overviews of active subfields mathematics?" is opinion based. Some people prefer Stilwell, some prefer Lang or even Kurant-Robbins. Many people think that none of these books cover modern PDE or data science, and so the answer is no.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princeton_Companion_to_Mathematics

Comment: Penrose’s book summarizes an impressive amount of modern pure mathematics, despite its main topic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_to_Reality

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations TickaJules and Lobic. Thank you also Deane, those look exactly like the books I'm looking for.

Comment: @markvs I see your point. Despite this, I think some of the most popular and helpful questions on this site are asking for books on topic so-and-so. Anyway, thank you for the feedback.